# QA'ing a web page using a Retriever (LangChain) - disappointing results

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I've been learning about using LangChain to build a simple app to QA a document/web page, I've been using these tutorials:

https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/vector_db_qa
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/ollama

Here is my very simple code:

```
llm = Ollama(
 base_url="http://localhost:11434",
 model="llama2",
 callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
  )


loader = WebBaseLoader("https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/vector_db_qa")
data = loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=100, chunk_overlap=50)
all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(data)


vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
 documents=all_splits, embedding=HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
 )

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever())
query = "How do you use Vectorstore Retriever Options?"
qa.run(query)
```

When I run it, I receive the response far from what I expect.

> Based on the context provided, it seems that Vectorstore Retriever Options is a feature in a document retrieval system that allows users to adjust how documents are retrieved from their vectorstore depending on the specific task at hand. The user can choose from different options for retrieving documents, such as using police (nominated by democrats and republicans) or adjusting the metadata of the documents.
>
> However, I cannot provide a definitive answer to your question without more information about the specific context and use case of Vectorstore Retriever Options. Could you please provide more details or clarify what you are trying to achieve with this feature?

Except for the passage about using the police making me giggle, there is no mentioning of Vectorstore Retriever options, while there is a passage about it in the web page. I'm kind of lost about what I am doing wrong here. Is it the limitation of the LLM I'm using or is there a  mistake in my approach overall?

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your query with below

"As an AI assistant you help in answering questions. You always refer to provided document source and provided detailed answer. Please answer following question, How do you use Vectorstore Retriever Options ?"

If this works for you, than you can defined well structured prompt for your queries. Your prompt should have Roles that will help AI assistant  to bring relevant results for you..

Comment: OK, I have tried a prompt based approach, copied from https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/ollama. Including the code, the prompt, the question (Task Decomposition), the source. The answer I've got is very long but doesn't mention Chain of thought or other details from the source. I'm confused. I thought using vectorstore.as_retriever the LLM should only be looking into the supplied context?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the vector store retriever option such as:

```
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="mmr"))
```

You can change the `search_type` option above as per the choice of your similarity search algorithm.

Also there are other advance retrievers that you can pass in your Retrieval QA chain such as:
SelfQueryRetriever, EnsembleRetrievar, LOTR etc. and you can use them as follows:

```
retriever = SelfQueryRetriever.from_llm(
llm, db, document_content_description, metadata_field_info, enable_limit=True, verbose=False
)
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm, chain_type="stuff", retriever=retriever)
```

You can try different retriever options and see which one works for you.

The problem with your solution looks like that your model is hallucinating. You can try to provide clear instructions to your model as to how it should respond and check how you chunked your documents.

The retriever will fetch the relevant document related to your query. Each chunk is converted into a document which the retriever will fetch so the documents must be chunked in an appropriate way.